# Is there a way to directly get a directory structure and parse it to Json in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to know if there is a way to get a specific directory structure and parse it to json so I can create a client-side treeview schema using a jquery plugin. thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried?  Are you trying to get a directory from the client machine or somewhere from the server?

Comment: from the server, i want to show some files stored on the server. Right now I'm using Directory class, but I don't know how to handle the result to send it to the client.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using JSON.NET:

```
JToken GetDirectory(DirectoryInfo directory)
{
    return JToken.FromObject(new
    {
        directory = directory.EnumerateDirectories()
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => GetDirectory(x)),
        file = directory.EnumerateFiles().Select(x => x.Name).ToList()
    });
}
```

Example usage:

```
var json = GetDirectory(new DirectoryInfo("...some path...")).ToString();
```

This will give you JSON that looks something like this:

```
{
    "directory":
    {
        "dirA": {
            "file" : [ "file0.txt", "file1.jpg" ]
        },
        "emptyDir": {
        }
    },
    "file": [ "file2.png" ]
}
```

Comment: it does, but also throws a lot of "\r\n", do you know which could be the reason?

Comment: "throws '\r\n'"? What do you mean? The default JSON.NET serializer will add formatting and newlines, yes. You can disable that if you want.

Comment: I'm using firebug and JSONLint to check the results, the response of the call comes with those characters and JSONLint says its invalid, but if I use the console printed response, it says is valid.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there is an easy way to convert a C# object to JSON using [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx).

You simply create a `List<>` that contains the data you want and then call

```
var wrapper = new { TreeData= list };
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(wrapper);
```

Comment: I understand how to parse an object to Json, but in this case, if I try to directly parse my Directory.EnumerateDirectories(directoryPath) to Json, it doesn't give a correct Json object, so I think the main problem is how to obtain the correct structure of the list before to parse it.

Comment: You will have to generate it yourself.  Create a list of objects like `List<DirectoryObject>` and give it some properties like `DirectoryName` and a list of its own children `List<DirectoryObject>`, then iterate recursively through the directory tree and fill your list.  Try parsing that into JSON

Answer (score -1):

You can create custom classes like:

```
abstract class DirectoryChildItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Directory : DirectoryChildItem
{
    public List<DirectoryChildItem> Childs { get; set; }
}

class File : DirectoryChildItem
{
}
```

Then you should traverse your file system using static class System.IO.Directory and create items using classes above.
After traversing file system use "return Json(obj)" method in your ASP.NET MVC action