# Converting a directory structure and parsing to JSON format in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, dynatree

I want to get the directory structure on server and parse it to json format so that I can send this to jQuery treeview plugin(Dynatree) through ajax. Dynatree accepts tree data something like this:

```
[
{"title": "Item 1"},
{"title": "Folder 2", "isFolder": true, "key": "folder2",
    "children": [
        {"title": "Sub-item 2.1"},
        {"title": "Sub-item 2.2"}
        ]
    },
{"title": "Folder 3", "isFolder": true, "key": "folder3",
    "children": [
        {"title": "Sub-item 3.1"},
        {"title": "Sub-item 3.2"}
        ]
    },
{"title": "Lazy Folder 4", "isFolder": true, "isLazy": true, "key": "folder4"},
{"title": "Item 5"}
]
```

In this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793627/is-there-a-way-to-directly-get-a-directory-structure-and-parse-it-to-json-in-c) @Timothy Shields shown a way to get Directory from DirectryInfo class and parse the structure to Json format like this:

```
JToken GetDirectory(DirectoryInfo directory)
{
return JToken.FromObject(new
{
    directory = directory.EnumerateDirectories()
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => GetDirectory(x)),
    file = directory.EnumerateFiles().Select(x => x.Name).ToList()
});
}
```

but the output is not like the above one and I don't know how can I manipulate it. I would appreciate if someone tell how I can produce above output from directory structure. Thanks.

**Edit:**
I have edited the question. I think the question is clear now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this instead : you could create a class with properties as Dynatree want (title, isFolder, ...).

```
class DynatreeItem
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public bool isFolder { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public List<DynatreeItem> children;

    public DynatreeItem(FileSystemInfo fsi)
    {
        title = fsi.Name;
        children = new List<DynatreeItem>();

        if (fsi.Attributes == FileAttributes.Directory)
        {
            isFolder = true;
            foreach (FileSystemInfo f in (fsi as DirectoryInfo).GetFileSystemInfos())
            {
                children.Add(new DynatreeItem(f));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            isFolder = false;
        }
        key = title.Replace(" ", "").ToLower();
    }

    public string DynatreeToJson()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented);
    }
}
```

The method "DynatreeToJson" return a string formatted in Json as Dynatree waits for it.
This is an example to use the DynatreeItem class :

```
DynatreeItem di = new DynatreeItem(new DirectoryInfo(@"....Directory path...."));
string result = "[" + di.DynatreeToJson() + "]";
```