# Retrieving directory and file structure using JSON.Net ( but without "directory", "file" keywords)

Tags: c#, json.net

I used JSON.Net to retrieve directory and file structure recursively. Referred this link( [Is there a way to directly get a directory structure and parse it to Json in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793627/is-there-a-way-to-directly-get-a-directory-structure-and-parse-it-to-json-in-c)). The result retreived as shown

```
RootDir
{
"directory":
{
    "dirA": {
        "file" : [ "file0.txt", "file1.jpg" ]
    },
    "emptyDir": {
    }
},
"file": [ "file2.png" ]
}
```

But I would like to exclude the "directory" and "file" keywords from the structure. My structure should look like this

```
RootDir
{
    "dirA": {
        " "file0.txt", "file1.jpg" 
    },
    "dirB": {
    }
},
 "file2.png"
```

I wanted only the directory names and file names rather than getting the directory names under a keyword and filenames under another keyword. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Not possible... you're second example is not valid json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get exactly the result you showed, because it would be invalid JSON.  However, you can come pretty close.  Try something like this:

```
public static string GetDirectoryAsJson(string path)
{
    return GetDirectoryAsJObject(new DirectoryInfo(path)).ToString();
}

public static JObject GetDirectoryAsJObject(DirectoryInfo directory)
{
    JObject obj = new JObject();
    foreach (DirectoryInfo d in directory.EnumerateDirectories())
    {
        obj.Add(d.Name, GetDirectoryAsJObject(d));
    }
    foreach (FileInfo f in directory.GetFiles())
    {
        obj.Add(f.Name, JValue.CreateNull());
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Then use it like this (for example):

```
string json = GetDirectoryAsJson(@"C:\Users\JohnDoe\Documents");
```

If the folder structure inside `C:\Users\JohnDoe\Documents` looked like this:

```
dirA
    dirA1
        foo.txt
    file0.txt
    file1.jpg
dirB
file2.png
```

Then the resulting JSON would look like this:

```
{
  "dirA": {
    "dirA1": {
      "foo.txt": null
    },
    "file0.txt": null,
    "file1.jpg": null
  },
  "dirB": {},
  "file2.png": null
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. Your answer has definitely helped me.