# C# Dynamically Map File System Using Recursion

Tags: c#, json, recursion

I am trying to dynamically map a folder structure into JSON format using C#.

Here are my method:

```
public static string StartJson(string Dir)
{
    try
    {
        StringBuilder Json = new StringBuilder();
        Json.Append("{\"FileSystem\" : [");
        if (Directory.GetDirectories(Dir).ToList().Count > 0)
        {
            Json.Append(GetDirectoryJson(Dir, 0));
        }

        if(Directory.GetFiles(Dir).ToList().Count > 0 && Directory.GetDirectories(Dir).ToList().Count == 0)
        {
            Json.Append(GetFileJSON(Dir));
        }
        else if(Directory.GetFiles(Dir).ToList().Count > 0 && Directory.GetDirectories(Dir).ToList().Count > 0)
        {
            Json.Append(",");
            Json.Append("{");
            Json.Append(GetFileJSON(Dir));
            Json.Append("}");
        }
        Json.Append("]}");//Close FileSystem
        return Json.ToString();
    }
    catch(Exception e) { return ""; }
}
public static int count = 0;
public static string GetDirectoryJson(string Dir, int Iteration)
{
    try
    {
        string path1 = Directory.GetParent(Dir).FullName;
        bool p = path.Equals(Directory.GetParent(Dir).FullName);
        StringBuilder Json = new StringBuilder();
        int folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path).ToList().Count;    
        foreach (string DirectoryPath in Directory.GetDirectories(Dir))
        {

            Json.Append("{");
            Json.Append("\"Folder\": [{");
            Json.Append("\"FolderPath\": " + "\"" + DirectoryPath.Replace('\\', '/') + "\"");
            if(Directory.GetDirectories(DirectoryPath).ToList().Count > 0)
            {
                Json.Append(",");
                Json.Append("\"Sub\": [");
                count++;
                Json.Append(GetDirectoryJson(DirectoryPath, Iteration++));
                Json.Append("]");
            }


            if (Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryPath).ToList().Count > 0)
            {
                Json.Append(",");
                Json.Append(GetFileJSON(Dir));
            }
            Json.Append("}");
            Json.Append("]");
            Json.Append("}");
        }
        return Json.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { return "Fail"; }
}

public static string GetFileJSON(string Dir)
{
    try
    {
        StringBuilder Json = new StringBuilder();
        Json.Append("\"Files\": [");
        int FileCount = 0;
        foreach (string FilePath in Directory.GetFiles(Dir))
        {
            Json.Append("{\"FilePath\": " + "\"" + FilePath.Replace('\\', '/') + "\"");
            FileCount++;
            if (Directory.GetFiles(Dir).ToList().Count == FileCount)
                Json.Append("}");
            else
                Json.Append("},");
        }
        Json.Append("]");

        return Json.ToString();
    }
    catch(Exception e) { return ""; }
}
```

I am getting really close, because this puts out MOSTLY correct JSON, when I use my test folder: `"C:\Users\sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN\Documents\Test"` I get the following JSON:

```
{  
   "FileSystem":[  
      {  
         "Folder":[  
            {  
               "FolderPath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1",
               "Sub":[  
                  {  
                     "Folder":[  
                        {  
                           "FolderPath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1/CantLogin_files",
                           "Sub":[  
                              {  
                                 "Folder":[  
                                    {  
                                       "FolderPath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1/CantLogin_files/images",
                                       "Files":[  
                                          {  
                                             "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1/CantLogin_files/CheckBrowser.js.download"
                                          },
                                          {  
                                             "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1/CantLogin_files/footer_right.jpg"
                                          },
                                          {  
                                             "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1/CantLogin_files/ga.js.download"
                                          },
                                          {  
                                             "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1/CantLogin_files/igpnl_up.gif"
                                          },
                                          {  
                                             "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1/CantLogin_files/ig_panel.css"
                                          },
                                          {  
                                             "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1/CantLogin_files/ig_shared.css"
                                          },
                                          {  
                                             "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1/CantLogin_files/jquery-1.9.0.min.js.download"
                                          },
                                          {  
                                             "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1/CantLogin_files/jquery.browser.js.download"
                                          },
                                          {  
                                             "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1/CantLogin_files/jquery.cookie.js.download"
                                          },
                                          {  
                                             "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1/CantLogin_files/qps_logo.png"
                                          },
                                          {  
                                             "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1/CantLogin_files/QPS_New.css"
                                          },
                                          {  
                                             "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1/CantLogin_files/ScriptResource(1).axd"
                                          },
                                          {  
                                             "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1/CantLogin_files/ScriptResource(2).axd"
                                          },
                                          {  
                                             "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1/CantLogin_files/ScriptResource(3).axd"
                                          },
                                          {  
                                             "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1/CantLogin_files/ScriptResource(4).axd"
                                          },
                                          {  
                                             "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1/CantLogin_files/ScriptResource.axd"
                                          },
                                          {  
                                             "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1/CantLogin_files/secondaryNavBG_right.jpg"
                                          },
                                          {  
                                             "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1/CantLogin_files/WebResource.axd"
                                          }
                                       ]
                                    }
                                 ]
                              }
                           ],
                           "Files":[  
                              {  
                                 "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1/CantLogin.html"
                              },
                              {  
                                 "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub1/UsersAndPass.csv"
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ],
               "Files":[  
                  {  
                     "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/New Hire Reporting Form - Copy.pdf"
                  },
                  {  
                     "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/New Hire Reporting Form.pdf"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }      {  
         "Folder":[  
            {  
               "FolderPath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub2",
               "Sub":[  
                  {  
                     "Folder":[  
                        {  
                           "FolderPath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub2/Test",
                           "Files":[  
                              {  
                                 "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub2/UsersAndPass - Big (737).csv"
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ],
               "Files":[  
                  {  
                     "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/New Hire Reporting Form - Copy.pdf"
                  },
                  {  
                     "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/New Hire Reporting Form.pdf"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }      {  
         "Folder":[  
            {  
               "FolderPath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/Sub3"
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "Files":[  
            {  
               "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/New Hire Reporting Form - Copy.pdf"
            },
            {  
               "FilePath":"C:/Users/sredmond.QPS_DOMAIN/Documents/Test/New Hire Reporting Form.pdf"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can see the JSON is almost correct but there is no comma seperating the folders found at the Root. You can put the JSON in here: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and see for yourself where the errors occur.

Anyway, my question is how to I make it so that those commas are being put in the right spot. Every time I try to add a comma or put a conditional in it will put the comma in random spots in the JSON.

Comment: Instead of  writing from scratch the json why not creating a treeview and then parse using json.net^

Comment: How would I get a tree view?

Comment: I'll show, just two mins

Comment: Ahh, I should have mentioned this is for a WebService thats supposed to return a JSON object for JavaScript to parse through and create a folder view

Comment: No matter what the purpose, you should generally not manipulate or build JSON *text* yourself. Instead, build a class structure that represents the data, fill out an instance of the data structure, then build the JSON from the data using a library like Json.Net.

Comment: @crashmstr, ok, but then how do I get a file structure dynamically?

Comment: @DevShadow Have a class `DirectoryNode` that has a `List<FileNode>` property called `Files` and a `List<DirectoryNode>` property called `Directories`? A JSON file is just a model of the data. Make a tree type structure that mirrors what you are trying to do in strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your responses. After looking deeper into JSON.NET I found a great answer here: [Is there a way to directly get a directory structure and parse it to Json in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15793627/is-there-a-way-to-directly-get-a-directory-structure-and-parse-it-to-json-in-c)

Answer (score 8):

Don't create a json by string operations...

I would create a custom class *Folder* and use a recursive method

```
public class Folder
{
    public string Path { set; get; }
    public List<string> Files { set; get; }
    public List<Folder> SubFolders { set; get; }

}

Folder GetFolderHierarchy(string root)
{
    var folder = new Folder();
    var dir = new DirectoryInfo(root);

    folder.Path = root;
    folder.Files =  dir.GetFiles().Select(x => x.FullName).ToList();

    folder.SubFolders = dir.GetDirectories().Select(x => GetFolderHierarchy(x.FullName))
                        .ToList();

    return folder;

}
```

Now, you can call it as

```
var folder = GetFolderHierarchy(@"d:\temp");
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(folder, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

**ADDITION**

In case you want to store relative paths instead of fullpath, the method can be changed to:

```
Folder GetFolderHierarchy(string root)
{
    var folder = new Folder();
    var dir = new DirectoryInfo(root);


    folder.Files = dir.GetFiles().Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
    folder.Path = dir.Name;
    folder.SubFolders = dir.GetDirectories().Select(x => GetFolderHierarchy(x.FullName))
                        .ToList();

    return folder;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem hides in **GetDirectoryJson** at the last `Json.Append("}")`
You need to add a comma between directories in the same level. You'll see more comma problems if you had a broader directory tree.

That being said, and as suggested, you are better off using a well established library which has been tested and used by many such as [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)